# Chart.js legend alignment left side

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, chart.js

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xo3zvwmplp)

How to move that legend to the left? I have tried to use `options:{legend:{position: 'left'}}`.

**Goal:**
[image]

`position: left` shifts the chart to the right what is not good for me:

[image]

Comment: `options: {
      legend: {
         position: 'left'
      }
   }`   should work.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, nooo, it doesn't work for me. I have written about it in my question

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, question was updated

Comment: see https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3934

Comment: If I'm not wrong there is something like align or aligment so try `{position: 'top',  align: 'left'}`

Comment: @Zydnar, I tried but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your code is correct and you will be able to align the legend as [following](https://github.com/dkichler/Chart.js/blob/66c06323cc8ed7460f9f8e49afc1283d44beea7d/docs/configuration/legend.md#align) in the future:

```js
legend: {
    position: "top",
    align: "start"
}
```

But the feature is currently not implemented at the current time (2019-03-30). The feature is already [merged](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/6141) and will be released with version 2.9. You either have to wait until [version 2.9](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/milestone/19) will be released or use a [development release](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/#development-releases), which is not recommended as they should only be used for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

with version 2.9 as suggested in the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/legend/position.html), use the plugins namespace
for e.g.

```
this.piechart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: data,
      options: {
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            position: 'right',
            align: 'center'
          }
        }
      }
    });
```